# PHP class get method always returns 0

Tags: php

I cannot workout why this script always returns 0. If I change it to echo getSKU() it works, but Quantity, Price or Name never seems to work. If anybody has any ideas please, please help this is irritating the life out of me!

```
<?php

session_start();

$sku = "0001";
if (!isset($_SESSION[$sku])) {
    $_SESSION[$sku] = new product($sku, 5);
} else {

}

echo $_SESSION[$sku]->getQuantity();

class product {

    var $sku;
    var $name;
    var $price;
    var $quantity;

    function __construct($par1, $par2) {
        $this->sku = $par1;
        $this->quantity = $par2;
    }

    function setSKU($x) {
        $this->sku = $x;
    }

    function getSKU() {
        echo $this->sku;
    }

    function setName($x) {
        $this->name = $x;
    }

    function getName() {
        echo $this->name;
    }

    function setPrice($x) {
        $this->price = $x;
    }

    function getPrice() {
        echo $this->price;
    }

    function setQuantity($x) {
        $this->quantity = $x;
    }

    function incrementQuantity() {
        $this->quantity++;
    }

    function getQuantity() {
        echo $this->quantity;
    }

}
```

Comment: you don't need `var`. You should set the value of the variables within the class such as `$sku = 0;`

Comment: @Martin I ran the code with the `$_SESSION` and it works fine though.

Comment: Your code works fine. [see here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/185b06b544a174f3fb9e93c1853b86ff6252119e)

Comment: @ChinLeung yes I've found even with using `$_SESSION` the code still works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't echo your attribute in get methodes

```
 echo $this->Variable;
```

you should always return them.

```
return $this->Variable;
```

> return returns program control to the calling module. Execution
>   resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation

for more information on return check the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `return` instead of `echo`. Your `get...`-methods currently don't return something (just implicitly `null`), they just `echo` the value you want to return.

To fix this, just replace in every `get...`-method `echo` with `return` - i.e.

```
function getQuantity() {
    return $this->quantity;
}
```

In addition to that, you should know, that you cant store objects in `$_SESSION` (actually you could, but then you have to implement the magic `__sleep` and `__wakeup`-methods..).
You should think about other solutions to store your products inside the session (i.e. serialize them)

Comment: While a improvement to the code this doesn't answer the issue.

Answer (score 0):

while the issues brought up in the other answers should definitely be addressed, to answer your question i believe the quantity is probably not set. can you try adding this line?

```
 $_SESSION[$sku]->setQuantity(5);
 $_SESSION[$sku]->getQuantity();
```